# Using ko.mapping plugin to edit and insert new records

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am using the ko.mapping plugin to map data from the server to the client.

I really love the fact is I can write the model once on the server and I don't have to rewrite the same model properties on the client.

I am doing something which I think is a pretty common task. I have a list of records and I am wanting to be able to insert and edit them. 
I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spnz/6rboqsqw/)

I have gotten as far as binding the list to the UI and have the editting of existing items working

I am stuck with how to allow inserting of new records.

My object is very basic

```
 [{
    "CustomerId": "1cd608c2-d980-4370-9861-c49e0811923c",
    "FirstName": "Adam",
    "LastName": "Jones",
    "StoreCustomerId": "9999 9999 9999 0002",
}]



var ViewModel = function (data) {
var self = this;

var mapping = {
    customers: {
        create: function (options) {
            console.log("mapping");
            var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
            console.log(vm);
            vm.FullName = ko.computed(function () {
                return vm.FirstName() + " " + vm.LastName();
            });

            return vm;
        }

    }
};

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self);

self.selectedCustomer = ko.observable();


self.delete = function (customer) {
    self.customers.remove(customer);
}

self.edit = function (customer) {
    console.log(customer);
    self.selectedCustomer = customer;
}

self.save = function (customer) {
    console.log(customer);
    //      console.log(customer.FirstName);
    self.customers.push(customer);
}
 }

 ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(dataFromServer));
```

Do I have to create a new observable something like

```
self.selectedCustomer = ko.observable();
```

When I click on the edit button the inputs are populated. How can I create a new record?

```
<div data-bind="with:selectedCustomer">
    <input placeholder="FirstName" data-bind="value:FirstName" />
    <input placeholder="LastName" data-bind="value:LastName" />
</div>
```

Could someone who is smarter then me please take a quick look at the fiddle and help out with what I am doing wrong. I think I am close but missing something.

Thanks for any assistance possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new customer viewmodel. You can do it using your existing mapping like this

```
var customer = mapping.customers.create({ data: {
    CustomerId: "",
    FirstName: "",
    LastName: "",
    StoreCustomerId: ""
}});
```

Then just push it to existing customers and select:

```
self.customers.push(customer);
self.selectedCustomer(customer);
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toboLLo4/)

Comment: Thanks Max. Is there anyway for the mapping plugin to do this for me? my model at the moment is changing allot and was hoping to be as lazy as possible.

Comment: Sorted it thanks. Just needed to play around slightly with how the model was generated